# Rocket.Chat App-Integration deployment error

Tags: typescript, npm, node-modules, rocket.chat

I would like to develop an app integration for Rocket.Chat, which uses a SlashCommand (e.g. /export) to provide a certain chatroom-history as pdf (in this room). As far as I searched the docs, I could not find any functionality provided through the Rocket.Chat Apps-Engine, the closest thing i have found would be MessageAttachements, but no idea if it is possible to upload files via this way. So I tried to upload a sample file via the Rocket.Chat REST API, but when it comes to uploading the file, I failed by trying to use a form-data object. Somehow I cannot use certain libraries, like form-data, fs, jsPdf etc. 
Simply importing it like so leads to an error:

```
import FormData = require('form-data');
```

```
packaging your app... packaged!
deploying your app... !
Error: Deployment error: Debug Failure. False expression.
    at Deploy.asyncSubmitData (C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/@rocket.chat/apps-cli/lib/commands/deploy.js:100:19)
    at async Deploy.run (C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/@rocket.chat/apps-cli/lib/commands/deploy.js:47:9)
    at async Deploy._run (C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/@rocket.chat/apps-cli/node_modules/@oclif/command/lib/command.js:43:20)
    at async Config.runCommand (C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/@rocket.chat/apps-cli/node_modules/@oclif/config/lib/config.js:172:9)
    at async Main.run (C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/@rocket.chat/apps-cli/node_modules/@oclif/command/lib/main.js:22:9)
    at async Main._run (C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/@rocket.chat/apps-cli/node_modules/@oclif/command/lib/command.js:43:20)
```

Package.Json:

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "@rocket.chat/apps-engine": "^1.14.0",
        "tslint": "^5.10.0",
        "typescript": "^2.9.1"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@types/form-data": "^2.5.0",
        "@types/jspdf": "^1.3.3",
        "@types/node": "^14.0.5",
        "form-data": "^3.0.0",
        "jspdf": "^1.5.3"
    }
}
```

My Rocket.Chat instance is hosted locally via docker.

What could be the problem?